# Pre population a PostgreSQL database

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql

So right now I have a simple Node.js API that uses PostgreSQL to query data, but what I want is to already have some data stored in the database when someone starts my project for the first time. What would we the best way to do it? Do I just hard code the data, or build some kind of a script that would run at the start of the server?

Comment: Depends on what you want to populate it with, But for the first you're probably gonna need to populate the database yourself.

Comment: I would strongly recommend writing a SQL script.  Depending on your requirements, perhaps the script can also (re)create the database itself.  Then save your SQL script along with the rest of your NodeJS project source in version control (e.g. on GitHub or Bitbucket).

Comment: You can populate the database manually or with prototype application code. When you get your initial database in the state you want it, you can dump it out so that it can be initialized with `pg_restore`. While you're developing your application you will probably change your mind many times about exactly how the schema should look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like someone in the comments mentioned.  The best way to go is to have an SQL script that runs on start.